# Cycle Multiple strings

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this macro which works fine but it's not flexible or as fast it should be. Basically I think it's better to add the `BanWords` in an array and cycle through them and delete rows.

```
 Sub delete_data(sh As Worksheet, col As String)
    Dim a As Variant, aWords As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim BanWords As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    Application.StatusBar = "Deleting Data..."
        
    'Exceptions List
    BanWords = "2019,2020,2021"
    
    sh.Activate
    
    ''Find Last Row
    With sh
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    'Reverse Iteration
    For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Range(col & i), "2019") <> 0 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        If InStr(1, Range(col & i), "2020") <> 0 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        If InStr(1, Range(col & i), "2021") <> 0 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are _many_ posts on SO about the speed of deleting rows.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+delete+row+performance+site%3A+stackoverflow.com

Comment: I am having a look around - but I havent seen any posts with multiple delete conditions - posts are checking only 1 condition

Comment: Basic principle is the same - build up a range and delete all rows once you're done looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: sorry I oversimplified and forgot to account for the "col" parameter in the code, so it was always checking ColA...

This would be faster:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    delete_data ActiveSheet, "C", "2019,2020,2021"
End Sub

'added a parameter for the list of words, for added flexibility
Sub delete_data(sh As Worksheet, col As String, termsList As String)
    
    Dim arr, i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim rngDel As Range, c As Range, v
    
    arr = Split(termsList, ",")
    lastrow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each c In sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, col), sh.Cells(lastrow, col)).Cells
        v = c.Value
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(v, Trim(arr(i))) > 0 Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then 'collect the row
                    Set rngDel = c
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, c)
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next c
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete 'delete all rows
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried various tests with this function but I am always getting an error "c = nothing" when reaching the end - and it errors out on the last line when trying to delete the rows

Comment: See my edits above